# Grails URL Mappings. Redirect 404 to URL e.g. http://www.mysite.com/404.html

Tags: grails, http-status-code-404, url-mapping

In my URL mappings I would like to send my application to an extrernal webpage URL for 404 errors. So, if my 404 page is hosted at http://www.myorganisation.com/404.html I would like my URL mapping to be:

```
"404"(uri:"http://www.myorganisation.com/404.html")
```

However, this does not work. I have also tried replacing 'uri' with 'url' with no success. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"404"(controller: "watevercontroller", action: "wateveraction")
```

And then within your "wateveraction"

```
redirect(url: "http://www.myorganisation.com/404.html")
```